# Привязка модели к маршруту и её использование в представлениях

Tags: php, laravel

Добрый день.

Как известно, в Laravel можно [привязать маршрут к модели](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding).

Если мы добавим такой маршрут:

```
Route::get('/users/{user}', 'UserController@show');
```

а в контроллере сделаем так (или ещё лучше, сделаем явную привязку к модели):

```
public function show(User $user)
```

то мы получим объект пользователя **без** User:find($id).

Обратиться к модели можно таким образом (даже из представления):

```
request()->route('user')
```

Вопрос: считается ли использование такой конструкции в представлении дурным тоном? Если да, то как лучше поступить в такой ситуации, что считается хорошей практикой?

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Laravel сообществе это считается нормальной практикой и называется привязкой модели, единственное почему лично я этим не пользуюсь - редко нужно просто выбрать по ключу, обычно идут дополнительные условия к выборке вместо простого `find`.

По сути это просто упрощение кода, лично не вижу ничего в этом дурного.